# When I try to read 34 data from file the program stops working

Tags: c++

I am trying to store data to array from file.When i try to read less than 33 data my program is working but when i try to read more than 34 data my program stops working.Is there any boundary to store data to array ?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>


using namespace std;

int array[50][2];

int main()
{
ifstream fp("20.txt");//when i change the txt file which stores 50 element it stops working
for(int row = 0; row < 20; row++){
    for(int column = 0; column < 2; column++){
        fp >> array[row][column];
    }
}
for(int row = 0; row < 20; row++){
    for(int column = 0; column < 2; column++){
        cout << array[row][column] << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
}
fp.close();
return 0;
```

Comment: In what way exactly does it "stop working"?

Comment: You are reading 40 elements in the shown code, assuming none of the file operations fail, which you don't check for.

Comment: It's always a good idea to make sure the file was opened successfully before trying to perform operations with it. It's also a good idea to make sure those operations work, like `if (!(fp >> array[row][column])) { /* handle error condition */ }`

Comment: Doesnt print anything only black screen

Comment: @user17732522 i know when i change the boundaries to 33 i can read 33 data but when it changed to 34 only black screen

Comment: If you output right after input (i.e. in the same nested loop), do you get anything? If yes, are those the values you expect?

Comment: @kaanaakin I don't understand. Either your code reads exactly 40 elements, or it has undefined behavior. Please show the contents of the file that you are using as well. Also add error checks.

Comment: Your code should check if `fp >> array[row][column]` was successful. Perhaps you are reading past the end of the file.

Comment: Please show the content of 20.txt which triggers the misbehaviour. Same for the file you describe as "when i change the txt file ".

Comment: This doesn't address the question, but you don't need to call `fp.close();`; the destructor will do that.

Comment: The programmer's secret weapon is the debugger. A debugger comes with every development worth using on desktop hardware. With a debugger you can control the execution of the program and monitor the changes in state. Typically you will use breakpoints to get to regions of interest in the program and then step through the code line-by-line while keeping an eye out for the program doing something unexpected like taking the wrong path or storing the wrong value.